# State space representation of autoregressive model with long lag

Tags: time-series, state-space-models

I am working with hourly data and using an autoregressive model:

$$y_t = \phi_1y_{t-1} + \phi_2y_{t-2} + \phi_{24}y_{t-24}+\varepsilon_t$$

Expressing this model using the standard state-space formulation ([Rob Hyndman slides](https://robjhyndman.com/talks/ABS3.pdf)) would need a 24-dimensional state-vector and the parameter restrictions $\phi_3...\phi_{23}=0$.

Is it possible to express this model more efficiently using fewer states?